# O365 Drop off library seems gone

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, drop-off-library

strangest thing happened today. In the site contents the dropofflibrary is gone. When I go to the URL sites/SiteCollection/DropOffLibrary it forwards me to a one of my sitepages. When I go to sites/SiteCollection/Forms/AllItems.aspx I see the contents of the dropofflibrary. What happened or better, how can I restore this?

Regards, Dennis

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem in my environment.

Check the permission settings for library, whether there are enough permissions to access the library